# Wiring a ceiling light to a ceiling fan box: what about ground?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I've only installed pendant lights before, and they came with a bracket with a green screw for grounding, so it was pretty simple. Now I'm trying to install a ceiling light that just has two wires to a plastic box that's wired for a ceiling fan...

Is it as simple as white to white and black to black, and I don't have to worry about grounding? It looks like there may be a ground wire already screwed at the top of the box (see circled close-up)?

Thanks so much for the help!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The screw on the back of the fixture might be for attaching a ground wire. Instructions say what?

Comment: Just black to black, white to white. No need to worry about grounding unless (1) the exterior of your light is metal; and (2) you will touch that metal regularly (which is unlikely for ceiling light).

Comment: Presumably you will use two screws into the tabs of the grounded metal box. This may ground the metal case.

Comment: If that is a plastic box I don't remember ever seeing a ground screw on plastic, a metal box usually has a grounding location /screw like yours that would be the location to attack the ground.